# Determine the script origin (php) of a dynamically inserted dom element

Tags: javascript, php, external, sandbox

I have a page with a select. Then `onchange`, based on the value selected, a URL is loaded into a div (using `$('myDiv').load()`) This URL is allowed to have javascript/jquery that executes, which means that it can manipulate the DOM outside of the div in which it loaded.

The desired functionality is to have dynamic tools based on which value is selected. To prevent unintended crossover of functionality, whenever the select value is changed, the previous value's elements/scripts/everything it loaded from the URL should be removed from the page. Ideally I would be able to search the DOM and find all elements that had some kind of attribute pointing to which script they were generated from.  I haven't been able to find any such attribute.  I don't want to rely on the outside script giving its elements a certain class to mark them as an element that needs to be removed.

Think of a hotel: The client doesn't need to make the room ready for the next person to stay in that room. The hotel is responsible for that.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: "To prevent unintended crossover of functionality, whenever the select value is changed, the previous value's elements/scripts/everything it loaded from the url should be removed from the page.". If these elements were all loaded into that div (which surely they must have been), then over-writing the contents of the div with the new content will surely remove them implicitly? Also, how is this relevant to PHP?

Comment: @ADyson The elements that were loaded into that div could have their location altered by the javascript that runs from that outside script.  (I in fact have this exact thing happening.)

It is relevant to PHP since PHP is being used as the server side language to load the main page and the outside script.

Comment: but all the changes you want to make are within the javascript, yes? so PHP won't come into it. You've already ruled out wanting to have the external script (PHP, presumably?) add extra classes or attributes, so you've effectively ruled out anything involving PHP. At that point, the server-side language is irrelevant, all that's relevant is the content that it returns.

Comment: Anyway you have a few options. You could loop every element that's returned from the external URL before you insert it into the DOM and add an extra attribute for later use, but that could easily slow things down. Or you could modify the server-side scripts to do this already, although as I mentioned above you seem to be against that. Or, you could refactor your app a bit so that the external scripts that are loaded don't directly manipulate the rest of the page - instead, get them to trigger custom events that your main page can listen for, and decide whether to act on.

Comment: that way, when the event is fired, it's your main page's code which intercepts it, and if it decides it needs to move an element based on that, it can add an attribute at that time, for instance. And also you have better control over what the other scripts are doing to the main page, and less tight coupling between the various components.

Comment: @ADyson I had a thought that if somehow the origin script were tracked, then I could use that information to determine what to remove and what to keep. I haven't been able to find any specific way to do that, but the tag is there in case someone does have a way to do that. Other than that you're absolutely correct.

Comment: sounds like it's the elements you need to track though, rather than the scripts. Once an element is in the DOM, nothing records its origin by default, so it's something you have to implement somehow. The server-side can only help if you're prepared to modify all the server-side scripts to inject extra stuff into the HTML.

Comment: @ADyson I do like the idea of the custom event triggering, allowing me to have more control.

Comment: I implemented a kind of dynamic medical questionnaire where different "components" (bits of HTML and JS) could be included in the page depending on various criteria. They all had to be indepdendent because any combination of them could be used, but if certain ones _were_ on the page together, then there were interactions between them that were required (e.g. to alter enabled/disabled fields or change default values). I used an event-based model for that, so that a "component" would emit an event, but wouldn't break if the other "component" listening for the event wasn't actually there.

Comment: It worked really well (if I do say so myself!). I think something similar would suit you here.